# Unable to install python package "toml"

Tags: python, numpy

I am following [this tutorial](https://dev.px4.io/en/simulation/ros_interface.html) for interfacing ROS and gazebo.

When I run

> make posix_sitl_default gazebo

```
[  0%] Built target git_driverframework
[  0%] Built target git_gps_devices
[  0%] Built target uorb_headers
[  2%] Built target df_driver_framework
[  3%] Built target git_mavlink2
[  3%] Built target git_mavlink
[  3%] Built target git_ecl
[  3%] Built target mixer_gen_legacy
[  4%] Generating mixer_multirotor_6dof.generated.h
[  4%] Generating mixer_multirotor_normalized.generated.h
[  4%] Generating mixer_multirotor.generated.h
[  5%] Built target ver_gen
('python import error: ', ImportError('No module named toml',))
('python import error: ', ImportError('No module named toml',))

Required python packages not installed.

On a GNU/Linux or MacOS system please run:
  sudo pip install numpy toml

On Windows please run:
  easy_install numpy toml

Required python packages not installed.

On a GNU/Linux or MacOS system please run:
  sudo pip install numpy toml

On Windows please run:
  easy_install numpy toml
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, so I use sudo pip install numpy toml but:

```
The directory '/home/nando/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/nando/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: toml in /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Apparently I already have the requirements satisfied, but I keep receiving the same error message when I run the first command.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running it with Root user or using sudo?

Comment: I have just done it, but I receive exactly the same error.

Comment: `If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag`. Did you try that too?

Comment: Yes, that removes the two warnings and goes directly to Requirement already satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was that I have python 2 and 3, I was installing toml in 3.
Running:

```
sudo -H pip2 install toml
```

Solved this for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing toml using pip3